# Excel: Yahoo Finance issue with values and how to automatically update cell from online CSV

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, excel-2010, yahoo-finance

Yahoo Finance has a fancy feature that allows you to download a CSV file with some information about stocks you choose. Using this format

`http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=STOCK1+STOCK2&f=INFO_NEEDED`

`&f=` accepts parameters according to **[this](http://kx.cloudingenium.com/content-providers/how-to-obtain-stock-quotes-from-yahoo-finance-you-can-query-them-via-excel-too/)** table. For example, to get the minimum price of titles UCG.MI and ISP.MI I use:

`http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=UCG.MI+ISP.MI&f=g`

**1)** The problem is that I get

```
66550
24240
```

While respectively the min prices are `6,6550` and `2,4240` (commas/dots are missing..). Why? How can I get the "right" values?

**2)** How can I import these values into Excel (and having the cells updated every X minutes re-grabbing the values from the CSV online source)? I tried with "Data"-"From web" but didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

I tried what you said and for it works perfecty fine in my case.

1) I think this is the way the cells are formatted in your case - Perhaps make sure they are numbers rather than general or something else.

2) There are refresh controls under the cells that have this date. Just go into a cell you defined the Web Query for and you will see the Refresh All button highlighted. You can use that to manually update the entire query or individual cells, but if you select the drop down go to 'Connection Properties' and a whole menu with option will appear (Background Refresh, Refresh every xx minutes', etc.).

Let me know if that's what you need?

KR
Davy

Comment: 1) OMG.. you're right.. I'm definitely blind.. :D
2) The issue is I can't set the online CSV file as Web Query (I get the window that asks me how to open the file, if I choose excel I get another instance of the file)..